# Cannot access Node.js API in my Angular app due to WebStorm's built-in server port mismatch

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webstorm

I am trying to follow the tutorial on creating a MEAN app on [scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular).

I am using the WebStorm IDE and after completely following through I am stuck with a problem that seems to emerge from WebStorm. If I click on the "Open in Chrome"-Button in the IDE I am referred to:
localhost:63342/scotch_mean_tutorial/views/index.html

However, the actual port that I specified in my `server.js` is 8080 file:

```
// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

I have built a node API and it works when I go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/todos
```

However, clicking on the "Open in Chrome" through my WebStorm IDE uses a different port (i.e. 63342) and thus I am left with the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/api/todos 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a javascript debug run configuration with the correct URL (`http://localhost:8080/api/todos`) and use this configuration to open your URL in browser. Another option: specify this URL in `Live Edit/Browser` tab of node.js run configuration you use to run your server.js and tick 'after launch' checkbox to automatically start the browser with this URL on server start.

Comment: See for reference: [https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html]

Answer (score 0):

In Webstorm 9, you can configure the port for debugging apps.  In Preferences:

Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Built-in Server Port